# How can I make my HTML form email me when a checkbox is checked using PHP POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox

I am trying to add a checkbox to a form and get the confirmation through an email. I am using the POST method.
All the rest of fields works fine, but checkbox doesn't...

Thanks!

## **HTML FORM**

```
<form class="form-contact" id="formulario" name="contacto" method="post" action="paraenviar.php">

<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" required class="fill" size="20" /><br /> 
      
<label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
<input name="empresa" id="empresa" type="text" required class="fill" size="20" /><br /> 

<label for="email">eMail</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" required class="fill" size="20" /><br /> 

<label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
<textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="26" rows="3" required class="textarea"></textarea><br />
        
<input type="checkbox" id="protecciondatos" name="protecciondatos" value="protecciondatos" required>

<label for="proteccion-datos">He leído y acepto la <a href="#">política de protección de datos</a> </label>
        
<br><br>
        
<input class="sendbutton" name="insert" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>

</form>
```

## **PHP**

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$mensaje = "NOMBRE: " . $nombre ." \r\n";
$mensaje .= "EMPRESA: " . $empresa . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "E-MAIL: " . $email . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "MENSAJE: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "FECHA DEL ENVÍO: " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$para = 'xxxx@xxx';
$asunto = 'Blablabla';

mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje));

?>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about the checkbox?  Where in the PHP code do you ever use its value?

Comment: So...which part of the PHP do you think is responsible for processing the checkbox value and putting into the email? As far as I can see, it doesn't work because you haven't written anything for it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as someone commented, you don't actually get the value from the form.

As of your question, your php code will be

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$protecciondatos=$_POST['protecciondatos'];


$mensaje = "NOMBRE: " . $nombre ." \r\n";
$mensaje .= "EMPRESA: " . $empresa . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "E-MAIL: " . $email . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "MENSAJE: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "FECHA DEL ENVÍO: " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$para = 'xxxx@xxx';
$asunto = 'Blablabla';

if($protecciondatos=="protecciondatos"){
   $hasAccepted="User accepted terms and conditions";
   $mensaje .= " ".$hasAccepted;
   mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje));
}
else{
   //error message, or whatever
}

?>
```

An even better way is to put everything in the if statement, like so:

```
<?php
    $protecciondatos=$_POST['protecciondatos'];
    if($protecciondatos=="protecciondatos"){
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $mensaje = "NOMBRE: " . $nombre ." \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "EMPRESA: " . $empresa . " \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "E-MAIL: " . $email . " \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "MENSAJE: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "FECHA DEL ENVÍO: " . date('d/m/Y', time());
        
        $para = 'xxxx@xxx';
        $asunto = 'Blablabla';
        $hasAccepted="User accepted terms and conditions";
        $mensaje .= " ".$hasAccepted;
        mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje));
    }
    else{
        //error message, or whatever
    }     
?>
```

Also, change

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="protecciondatos" name="protecciondatos" value="protecciondatos" required>

<label for="proteccion-datos">He leído y acepto la <a href="#">política de protección de datos</a> </label>
```

to

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="protecciondatos" name="protecciondatos" value="protecciondatos" required>

<label for="protecciondatos">He leído y acepto la <a href="#">política de protección de datos</a> </label>
```

As it's not correct.

Comment: I have not written the PHP command because I have not know what I have to write....

Comment: Maybe I have not made correctly the question. I am wondering if it is possible to show in the email that the checkbox has been checked by adding an instruction in the PHP code.

Comment: @Albert totally possible, however I would create a custom message, as reported (I've just modified my answer), or else it will show "protecciondatos" (if you just insert the checkbox's value). I also assume that you don't send the mail if the checkbox condition isn't met (which you should consider)